# Cross-account pass role is not allowed in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an account DEV trying to create a lambda in account Module. When the code (a lambda that gets triggered by S3) in DEV attempts to create the lambda in MODULE I get the error "Cross-account pass role is not allowed"[Symbol]

The process goes like this: I add a file to DEV S3 this lambda gets triggered and is supposed to call lambda `await getLambdaClient(opts).send(new CreateFunctionCommand(params))` where opts are the temporary STS creds obtained using the `moduleAssumeRole`

I am using CDK/Typescript:

In my MODULE account I create role:

```
// Basic role for module lambdas created on the fly
const moduleAssumeRole = new Role(this, 'ModuleAssumeRole', {
  roleName: 'moduleAssumeRole',
  assumedBy: new CompositePrincipal(
    new AccountPrincipal(DEV_ACCOUNT_ID),
    new ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com')
  )
})
moduleAssumeRole.addToPolicy(
  new PolicyStatement({
    actions: [
      'iam:*',
      'sts:*',
      'lambda:*',
      'logs:*',
      'xray:PutTelemetryRecords',
      'xray:PutTraceSegments'
    ],
    resources: ['*']
  })
)
```

In my dev stack:

```
const moduleDeployerLamdba =  new NodejsFunction(this, 'DeployLambda', {
  ...  
  environment: {
    MODULE_ASSUME_ROLE: moduleAssumeRoleArn
  }
))

// I dont think these are needed here but hey... trying passrole everywhere
moduleDeployer.addToRolePolicy(
  new PolicyStatement({
    actions: ['lambda:*', 'logs:*', 's3:*'],
    resources: ['*']
  })
)

moduleDeployer.addToRolePolicy(
  new PolicyStatement({
    actions: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
    resources: ['*']
  })
)

moduleDeployer.addToRolePolicy(
  new PolicyStatement({
    actions: ['iam:PassRole'],
    resources: ['*']
  })
)
```

In my deploy code on DEV I use the STS client and pass it the moduleAssumeRoleArn to get credentials to use to deploy lambda to MODULE account.

Reading the dozens of posts/blogs on this I cannot find an answer. Docs keep referring to a user having permission to pass a role - not sure what user they are talking about here but the CDK is deployed with AdministratorAccess API keys.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a CDK synth-time error, CDK deploy-time error, or Lambda runtime error?

Comment: A lambda error - when I add a file to DEV S3 this lambda gets triggered and is supposed to call lambda `await getLambdaClient(opts).send(new CreateFunctionCommand(params))` where `opts` are the temporary STS creds obtained using the `moduleAssumeRole`

Comment: Why not use the standard [cross-account Assume Role](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/) pattern?  The DEV Lambda role assumes a MODULE role, which has the neccessary create Lambda permissions in MODULE.  The MODULE role's trust policy allows the DEV Lambda role to assume it.

Comment: Isn't that the pattern I am using? DEV lambda, using the assumerole which is created under MODULE and has DEV acct ID as a principal as well as all lambda permissions. DEV lambda uses this role to get temp creds and tries to deploy. This actually used to work a few months ago but revisiting now I get this pass role thing. Docs seem to mention that pass role is to control who can grant assume permissions but no idea what that "user" is. Certainly not the deploy one which has every permissions.

Comment: On your linked doc they have `RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/role-on-source-account` - I am using same exact pattern and the rolearn is the assume role I created above

Comment: Good grief...  I messed up the format of passing the assume credentials to the lambda client ....  I was passing assumed creds but my little piece of code I use to merge config was blotched and didn't format things correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some least-priviledge adjustments and clean-ups:

`ModuleAssumeRole` should narrowly trust the DEV Lambda Role only. The Account Principal is overly broad.  The Lambda service principal is invalid.

```js
const moduleAssumeRole = new Role(this, 'ModuleAssumeRole', {
  roleName: 'moduleAssumeRole',
  assumedBy: new CompositePrincipal(
    new ArnPrincipal(DEV_LAMBDA_ROLE_ARN), // best option for least-privilege access
    new AccountPrincipal(DEV_ACCOUNT_ID),  // valid, but very broad
  )
})
```

For least-privilege, the DEV `DeployLambdaRole` should be allowed to assume `ModuleAssumeRole` only, not every role.

```js
moduleDeployer.addToRolePolicy(
  new PolicyStatement({
    actions: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
    resources: [MODULE_ASSUME_ROLE_ARN] // "*" valid, but not least-privilege
  })
)
```

Remove the other `moduleDeployer.addToRolePolicy` calls.  Not needed.

Note the circular dependency between the two roles when least-privilege is applied.  `ModuleAssumeRole` needs the `DeployLambdaRole` ARN for its trust policy.  `DeployLambdaRole` needs the `ModuleAssumeRole` ARN for its permissions policy.  The easiest way to deal with this is to use explicit role names instead of CDK generated names in this case.  Or don't use least-privilege.

Answer (score 0):

So I am leaving this question with my silly mistake up because the error message made it a bit vague for me to find the culprit so perhaps will help someone. All my CDK code was correct but I messed up passing the assumed temp credentials to the lambda client. I use a little config merge utility and it essentially discarded the assumed creds in the process.  Bad coder. No pizza.